# Why is my javascript slider breaking?

Tags: javascript

I've tried to figure this out for hours now. I am not that great with JS. Hopefully someone smarter than I can easily see what the issue is here. I have a tabbed view, and each view should have a slider. The slider works in the first tab, but second tab it breaks. The javascript function is not being passed into the subsequent tabs. URL to view this:
http://goo.gl/yZISjS

The code for the tabbed views and the slider:

```
    <!-- http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal -->
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
        <label for="tab1">Spring Wedding</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content ChefsPick">
          <div id="slides">
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/summer_image1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Summer Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Sweet Maryland Crab Cakes with Herb Remoulade are absolutely scrumptious and the perfect spring wedding hors d'oeuvres.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/summer_image2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Summer Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Chinese Chicken Salad in Miniature Tortilla Cups is a bite size signature delight that can be butler passed or displayed on a buffet.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/summer_image3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Summer Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Vegetable Spring Rolls add the perfect amount of crunch to your wedding hors d'oeuvre selection.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
        <label for="tab2">Summer Wedding</label>
        <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content ChefsPick">
          <div id="slides" style="overflow: hidden;">
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/summer_image1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Summer Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Sweet Maryland Crab Cakes with Herb Remoulade are absolutely scrumptious and the perfect spring wedding hors d'oeuvres.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/summer_image2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Summer Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Chinese Chicken Salad in Miniature Tortilla Cups is a bite size signature delight that can be butler passed or displayed on a buffet.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/summer_image3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Summer Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Vegetable Spring Rolls add the perfect amount of crunch to your wedding hors d'oeuvre selection.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
        <label for="tab3">Fall Wedding</label>
        <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content ChefsPick">
          <div id="slides">
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/spring_image1.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Spring Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Sweet Maryland Crab Cakes with Herb Remoulade are absolutely scrumptious and the perfect spring wedding hors d'oeuvres.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/spring_image2.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Spring Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Chinese Chicken Salad in Miniature Tortilla Cups is a bite size signature delight that can be butler passed or displayed on a buffet.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="top">
                                    <img src="../wp-content/themes/wolfgang-puck/assets/img/spring_image3.jpg" alt="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                        <div class="title">Spring Wedding: Hors D'oeuvres</div>
                                        <p>Vegetable Spring Rolls add the perfect amount of crunch to your wedding hors d'oeuvre selection.</p>
                                    </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
        <label for="tab4">Winter Wedding</label>
        <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content">
          <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla?</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab5" />
        <label for="tab5">The Classics</label>
        <div id="tab-content5" class="tab-content">
          <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla?</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've moved all the code around multiple times and can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code here as it will allow people looking at this later to be sure they get to see the issue. Also, it's unclear which slider and which tab. Without more concise code, we cannot really help you properly.

Comment: You've got multiple divs with id="slides". I would start by either putting all your tabs into one div with that id or giving the divs unique IDs and ensuring your slidesjs() call catches them all. ID attribute values on html elements should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently calling your slider with this :

```
$("#slides").slidesjs({
    width: 480,
    height: 380,
    play: {
          active: true,
            // [boolean] Generate the play and stop buttons.
            // You cannot use your own buttons. Sorry.
          effect: "slide",
            // [string] Can be either "slide" or "fade".
          interval: 3000,
            // [number] Time spent on each slide in milliseconds.
          auto: false,
            // [boolean] Start playing the slideshow on load.
          swap: true,
            // [boolean] show/hide stop and play buttons
          pauseOnHover: false,
            // [boolean] pause a playing slideshow on hover
          restartDelay: 2500
            // [number] restart delay on inactive slideshow
    }
  });
```

It means you call a slider on `#slides` element. As this selector is an ID, it will only apply this to the first one it get.

So, considering you have multiple sliders, you should use classes instead.

```
$(".slides").slidesjs({
    width: 480,
    height: 380,
    play: {
          active: true,
            // [boolean] Generate the play and stop buttons.
            // You cannot use your own buttons. Sorry.
          effect: "slide",
            // [string] Can be either "slide" or "fade".
          interval: 3000,
            // [number] Time spent on each slide in milliseconds.
          auto: false,
            // [boolean] Start playing the slideshow on load.
          swap: true,
            // [boolean] show/hide stop and play buttons
          pauseOnHover: false,
            // [boolean] pause a playing slideshow on hover
          restartDelay: 2500
            // [number] restart delay on inactive slideshow
    }
  });
```

Then, remove `id="slides"`in your HTML and add the class `slides` instead.

*For the record: you can use only one specific ID per document >* https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

**EDIT : 2nd issue**

Now, slidesJS can't get the real dimensions of each of your sliders, due to the use of `display: none;` on your tabs :

```
/* line 328, ../sass/style.scss */
html .wrapper.weddings .tabs .tab-content, body .wrapper.weddings .tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 838px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  min-height: 680px;
  border-right: 1px solid #BC9A95;
  border-left: 1px solid #BC9A95;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BC9A95;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

So, you need to find a solution to mask your tabs without using `display: none;`

You could try something like :

```
html .wrapper.weddings .tabs .tab-content, body .wrapper.weddings .tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  /*display: none; */
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 838px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  min-height: 680px;
  border-right: 1px solid #BC9A95;
  border-left: 1px solid #BC9A95;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BC9A95;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  /* vvvv there vvvv */
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1 /* hacky, but it works */ 
}
```

And then, to make it appear :

```
/* line 433, ../sass/style.scss */
html .wrapper.weddings .tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"], body .wrapper.weddings .tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10; /* or whatever default value you set */
}
```

Comment: you are very smart. may i ask how i would add a conditional that checks for both # and . since in my code i am using this script elsewhere with #?

Comment: You shouldn't use same ID on multiple elements, just fix your HTML to remove that. Using the same ID for multiple elements will always cause issues. So, just clean it, and you'll be fine.

Comment: unfortunately this did not fix the issue. i updated the js, updated the html to use classes, and updated the css from # to class. - the javascript is now being passed to the other elements but it is just blank. curious if you know why?

Comment: `slidejs()` is called on all `.slides` (you can see it with the inspector), but now, you have another issue : as you call slidejs on document ready, all the unvisible sliders (display:none). So slidejs calculates each slider dimensions when they are not displayed, so each slider width and height are 0 :)

Comment: ok thank you so much. i obviously need some more training on JS for these type of issues. i really appreciate your time and effort, and i will work with this to see if i can get it to work.

Comment: Well, this piece of code was about HTML and CSS issues mostly :)

Comment: i finally had a chance to test this, and it worked perfectly. many thanks again!